# Can you efficiently change a lower level Docker container, without rebuilding all the apps that rely on it?

Tags: docker

I've seen that you can layer Docker containers.  As an example, lets say we had a set up with a Java container at the base, say running Java 6, a Tomcat container running on top of the Java container, and say 400 unique application containers running on top of the Tomcat container.

Is there a way to switch to Java 7, replace the Java 6 container with a Java 7 container, and not have to rebuild 400 applications? and then deploy 400 applications? and then shut down the original 400 applications?

Basically I'm looking for the best way to make a low level change to every application running in your environment.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: No. There is not. You can automate your builds, but you will need to build them again, from the first changed layer up. Maybe we will get an include mechanism in the future, but we don't yet.